# C++ Remote - Having files local and on the host

Tags: c++, sftp, remote-access, netbeans-8, file-copying

i have the following problem. I am using Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 7. I configure a C/C++ Build Host which is a linux system. On this linux-system i have a c/c++ projekt. Then I create a new project with right-click on this host -> New C/C++ Project and than --> C/C++ Project with Existing Source.

This work fine. On my windows-machine i can change the code, can compile and run the project. This all happens on the linux machine.

But the project and the sourcefiles only exist on the host-machine. Is there a way, that each compiling the data (source-files and the project) was copying to the local-machine so that the files exist local and on the host?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd discourage such a way of keeping code in sync between two machines. What you would like to achieve is having code (and I count the project files as code here) in sync between two machines. That you work on one and compile on the other is not that relevant here.

The - in my opinion by far - best way to keep things in sync is to have some kind of version control system, i.e., a repository. I prefer git in almost every case. You can - and should - regularly commit your changes to a repository, and then you can simply push/pull the changes to keep all your machines in sync.